# Mor-flo gas hot water heater pilot light goes out when running

Tags: wiring, plumbing, bathroom, concrete, shower

I have an old More-Flo gas water heater. I replaced the thin copper line that goes bad. The control valve has 4 lines coming from the bottom of it: the main gas line, the pilot line, the thermocouple line, and a fourth line I can't identify.

I can get the pilot to stay lit but as I turn the valve to run it lights for about 30 seconds and goes out. Are there any specific settings for the lines and what is the fourth line for? Any help would be appreciated and I thank you for your time.